# How to separate routes inside a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following on my index.js

```
<Router  routes={routes} />

I would like to have routes section in a separate file, so far I tried this:
routes.js

export default (
    <div>
        <Route path="/" component={AppComponent}>
            <Route path="/someother" component={AddProductComponent} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/products" component={ListProductComponent} />
    </div>
);
```

and in index.js

```
import routes from './routes';
<Router  routes={routes} />
```

For some reason the app shows blank now. looks like the routes are not rendered.

UPDATE, this is my whole index.js except missing imports due stackoverflow companing about too much code put:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    products: productReducer,
});

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router  routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Update routes.js

```
export default (
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={AppComponent}/>

        <Route path="/products" component={ListProductComponent}>
            <Route path="/details/:productId" component={AddProductComponent} />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the switch:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/someother" component={AppComponent}>
    <Route path="/products" component={ListProductComponent} />
    <Route path="/" component={AppComponent}>
</Switch>
```

Also, your code will only show AppComponent, as any url (`/`, `/home`, `/etc`) starts with the slash you put in the `path` attribute. You might want that as a last page, a fallback.

The `path` attribute works with a wildcare: `path="/"` -> `path="/**"` are functionally the same. If you want an exact path, add `exact` to the Route.

---

If you mean to split routes into seperate files, you can do this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path={"/user"} component={UserRouter}/>
    <Route path={"/product"} component={ProductRouter}/>
</Switch>
// In userRouter.jsx:
export function UserRouter() {
    return <Switch>
        <Route exact path={"/user/list"} component={UserListPage}/>
        <Route exact path={"/user/signup"} component={userSignupPage}/>
        <Route exact path={"/user/profile"} component={UserProfilePage}/>
    </Switch>
};
```

Comment: still blank page

Comment: Expanded my answer. If you have a blank page, you likely have an error.

Comment: im checking the dev tool, no errors in console, jus that blank page showing, thou i just want a single file for all routes, not for every entity a single route file